# SASS - user agent stylesheet overriding link colours

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

This might seem like a really silly question but I'm having trouble with webkit overriding my SASS.

In my view I have:

```
<%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path, :class => 'button button-new' %>
```

And in application.css.scss:

```
.button{
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;

    a{
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.button-new{
    background-color: #428bca;
    padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;   
}
```

However the link color in my browser is the default blue with an underline. When I inspect the element under developer tools, styling for the link is not being seen/read. Instead the link is using styling from user agent stylesheet.

I know I must be doing something fairly simple wrong but I can't for the life of me spot it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your SASS like this:

```
.button{
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;

  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

because your link has `.button` class.

Comment: I'm so silly! Of course it does. Thanks, this sorted out the problem nicely. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me :)

Comment: There is another way, which I'll put in an answer. Please accept this as it's the right one - my answer will be for reference

Answer (score 0):

**Structure**

Your link will create an `<a href=` element with the class `button`

This means your styling will not match your HTML structure, as you've got `a` nested  inside the `button` class, the CSS will basically be looking for this:

```
<div class="button">
   <a href="..."></a>
</div>
```

--

The way you want it to work is like this:

```
<a href="..." class="button"></a>
```

To do this in the SCSS, you need to style the `a` tag [in line with your class](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector), like this:

```
a.button{
    font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    text_decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this up, it's really helpful :)

Comment: No problem! It can be confusing, so I hope it helps